# LAX terminal 6 to terminal 7 transfer and TSA and immigration

Tags: customs-and-immigration, layovers, tsa

On an Alaska Airlines flight from Puerto Vallarta to LAX terminal 6. Then a United Airlines flight departing from terminal 7 arriving at SFO. It looks like I can walk from Terminal 6 to terminal 7 without going through TSA. Only carrying on baggage.

Is this correct?

Where to I clear customs and immigration? LAX or SFO?

Is this possible with a 2:15 minute window?

Answer (score 5):

When your flight (Alaska 250) lands at LAX Terminal 6, you will follow a sterile corridor to Terminal 7, where you will go through immigration, baggage claim and customs (and then drop your checked bags for your connecting flight, if you're on a single booking). You will then go out the doors into the Terminal 7 arrivals hall. You have to go back upstairs to departures and go through security again for your connecting flight. (All international arrivals have to go through security again.)

If there aren't huge lines at immigration this should be easily doable in 2:15. Of course if you have booked separate tickets then you are on your own if you miss the connecting flight. On the same ticket, the airline will take care of rebooking you. Also if you're on separate tickets, then you can't drop your bags again past customs, but you have to take them upstairs to check-in and check them in for your separate flight. If you do have separate tickets, keep your airline's domestic check-in deadlines in mind. You may not have as much time as you think.

Comment: United allows on-line check in up to 24 hours before the flight, so that can be done before boarding the first flight. The OP only has carry-on baggage. Just be at the gate at least 15 (I would aim for 30) minutes before departure time.

Comment: Hmm. I didn't see the bit about only carrying on baggage. But it still sounds like he's on separate tickets. I would be a bit nervous, personally.